# Missing join for type table in EF Core query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 7 code-first to build my database.

In my database, I have a `Request` which has a child `ChangeDetail`.  Both request and changes have a child link to `Status => StatusType`.  My problem is, the `ChangeDetail` object is not getting the status records. I looked at the SQL generated the repository and the link from `Request => Status` is there, but the link from `ChangeDetail => Status` is not in the query so I messed up the relationship somewhere.

Here is my `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      // this is a 1:N - Requests and RequestType
      modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
          .HasOne(x => x.RequestType)
          .WithMany(x => x.Requests);

      // this is a 1:N - Requests and ChangeDetail
      modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
          .HasMany(x => x.ChangeDetail)
          .WithOne(x => x.Request);

      // this is a N:N - Requests and Status
      modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
          .HasMany(x => x.Statuses)
          .WithMany(x => x.Requests);

      //this is a N:N - ChangeDetail and Status
      modelBuilder.Entity<ChangeDetail>()
          .HasMany(x => x.Statuses)
          .WithMany(x => x.Changes);

      // this is a 1:N - Status and StatusType
      modelBuilder.Entity<Status>()
          .HasOne(x => x.StatusTypes)
          .WithMany(x => x.Statuses);

      // this is a 1:1 - self join parent and child
      modelBuilder.Entity<Taxonomy>()
          .HasOne(x => x.ParentTaxonomy)
          .WithMany(c => c.ChildTaxonomy)
          .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
}
```

And here is an abbreviated database diagram generated in SSMS. SQL Server sees the correct relationships:

[image]

I think the problem is in my repository method. Is the query missing something?

```
public async Task<List<Request>> GetAllRequestsAsync()
{
    List<Request> result = new();

    using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        result = await context.Request
                .Include("ChangeDetail")
                .Include("ChangeDetail.Statuses")
                .Include("ChangeDetail.Statuses.StatusTypes")
                .Include("Statuses")
                .Include("Statuses.StatusTypes")
                .Include("RequestType")
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    var orderedResult = result.OrderByDescending(x => x.RequestId).ToList();

    return orderedResult;
}
```

Here is the query generated by EF Core. In the main query you will see two `LEFT JOIN` statements. The second join is the `Request => Status => StatusType` which works as expected. The one above that is for the `ChangeDetail => Status => (status type missing)` which is missing its join to the `StatusType` table:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (48ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [r].[RequestId], [r].[Change], [r].[Justification], [r].[LegacyId], [r].[ModifyDate], [r].[ModifyUser], [r].[RequestTypeId], [r].[SubmitDate], [r].[SubmitUser], [r0].[RequestTypeId], [t0].[ChangeDetailId], [t0].[ChangeText], [t0].[CurrentL1], [t0].[CurrentL2], [t0].[CurrentL3], [t0].[CurrentL4], [t0].[CurrentL5], [t0].[LegacyId], [t0].[ModifyDate], [t0].[ModifyUser], [t0].[NewL1], [t0].[NewL2], [t0].[NewL3], [t0].[NewL4], [t0].[NewL5], [t0].[RequestId], [t0].[SubmitDate], [t0].[SubmitUser], [t0].[StatusId], [t0].[ChangeDetailId0], [t0].[RequestId0], [t0].[StatusDate], [t0].[StatusTypeId], [t0].[SubmitUser0], [t0].[ChangeDetailId00], [t0].[StatusesStatusId], [t1].[StatusId], [t1].[ChangeDetailId], [t1].[RequestId], [t1].[StatusDate], [t1].[StatusTypeId], [t1].[SubmitUser], [t1].[StatusTypeId0], [t1].[StatusTypeName], [t1].[RequestId0], [t1].[StatusesStatusId], [r0].[RequestTypeName]
FROM [Request] AS [r]
INNER JOIN [RequestType] AS [r0] ON [r].[RequestTypeId] = [r0].[RequestTypeId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [c].[ChangeDetailId], [c].[ChangeText], [c].[CurrentL1], [c].[CurrentL2], [c].[CurrentL3], [c].[CurrentL4], [c].[CurrentL5], [c].[LegacyId], [c].[ModifyDate], [c].[ModifyUser], [c].[NewL1], [c].[NewL2], [c].[NewL3], [c].[NewL4], [c].[NewL5], [c].[RequestId], [c].[SubmitDate], [c].[SubmitUser], [t].[StatusId], [t].[ChangeDetailId] AS [ChangeDetailId0], [t].[RequestId] AS [RequestId0], [t].[StatusDate], [t].[StatusTypeId], [t].[SubmitUser] AS [SubmitUser0], [t].[ChangeDetailId0] AS [ChangeDetailId00], [t].[StatusesStatusId]
    FROM [ChangeDetail] AS [c]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [s].[StatusId], [s].[ChangeDetailId], [s].[RequestId], [s].[StatusDate], [s].[StatusTypeId], [s].[SubmitUser], [c0].[ChangeDetailId] AS [ChangeDetailId0], [c0].[StatusesStatusId]
        FROM [ChangeDetailStatus] AS [c0]
        INNER JOIN [Status] AS [s] ON [c0].[StatusesStatusId] = [s].[StatusId]
    ) AS [t] ON [c].[ChangeDetailId] = [t].[ChangeDetailId0]
) AS [t0] ON [r].[RequestId] = [t0].[RequestId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [s0].[StatusId], [s0].[ChangeDetailId], [s0].[RequestId], [s0].[StatusDate], [s0].[StatusTypeId], [s0].[SubmitUser], [s1].[StatusTypeId] AS [StatusTypeId0], [s1].[StatusTypeName], [r1].[RequestId] AS [RequestId0], [r1].[StatusesStatusId]
    FROM [RequestStatus] AS [r1]
    INNER JOIN [Status] AS [s0] ON [r1].[StatusesStatusId] = [s0].[StatusId]
    INNER JOIN [StatusType] AS [s1] ON [s0].[StatusTypeId] = [s1].[StatusTypeId]
) AS [t1] ON [r].[RequestId] = [t1].[RequestId0]
ORDER BY [r].[RequestId], [r0].[RequestTypeId], [t0].[ChangeDetailId], [t0].[ChangeDetailId00], [t0].[StatusesStatusId], [t0].[StatusId], [t1].[RequestId0], [t1].[StatusesStatusId], [t1].[StatusId]
```

And finally here are the repository objects. FYI, there may be some unnecessary annotations in the models. I prefer everything to be in FluentAPI but I'm still learning so its not quite there yet. It's a little confusing because blog articles don't always tell you if it's EF or EF Core, or what version.

```
public class Request
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>changed from "navarchar(max)" to "text" for sqlite testing db </summary>
    [Required]
    [MinLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Justification { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
    public string Change { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string SubmitUser { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public DateTime SubmitDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string? ModifyUser { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ChangeDetail> ChangeDetail { get; set; } = new();

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Status.RequestId))]
    public virtual List<Status> Statuses { get; set; } = new();

    public int RequestTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual RequestType RequestType { get; set; } = new();
    public int LegacyId { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeDetail
{
    public int ChangeDetailId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    [Column (TypeName ="nvarchar(MAX)")]
    public string? ChangeText { get; set; }

    [Column (TypeName="nvarchar(150)")]
    public string? CurrentL1 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string? CurrentL2 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string? CurrentL3 { get; set;}

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string? CurrentL4 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string? CurrentL5 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")] 
    public string? NewL1 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")] 
    public string? NewL2 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")] 
    public string? NewL3 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")] 
    public string? NewL4 { get; set;}

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")] 
    public string? NewL5 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string SubmitUser { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public DateTime SubmitDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string? ModifyUser { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; } = new();
    public int LegacyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Status.ChangeDetailId))]
    public virtual List<Status> Statuses { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Status
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Request.RequestId))]
    public int? RequestId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ChangeDetail.ChangeDetailId))]
    public int ChangeDetailId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")] 
    public string SubmitUser { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Request> Requests { get; set; } = new();

    [ForeignKey(nameof(StatusType.StatusTypeId))]
    public int StatusTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual StatusType StatusTypes { get; set; } = new();
    public virtual List<ChangeDetail> Changes { get; set; } = new();
}

public class StatusType
{
    public int StatusTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string StatusTypeName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public virtual IEnumerable<Status> Statuses { get; set; } = new List<Status>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of the cause of the issue, but that Status entity/configuration looks a bit suspect:

```
public class Status
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Request.RequestId))]
    public int? RequestId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ChangeDetail.ChangeDetailId))]
    public int ChangeDetailId { get; set; }
    // ...
```

To me, this says that Status belongs to ChangeDetail, yet your configuration is  doubling up associating it to Requests and ChangeDetail.. The RequestId is null-able.  This looks like a case of de-nomalization. I would suggest removing the RequestId and Requests, and a request can just access the Status through its ChangeDetail(s). Does it make sense that a Request would have a different status reference than the change details associated with the Request?

When eager loading, I highly recommend using the expression-based methods:

```
.Include(x => x.ChangeDetail)
   .ThenInclude(x => x.Status)
       .ThenInclude(x => x.StatusType)
```

Rather than magic strings. The advantage of using the expression version is that it avoids surprises by being validated at compile time. Renaming a navigation property flows through automatically.

I also highly recommend creating a view model or DTO for the data being passed back and projecting a result rather than passing back an entity graph like this, especially for result sets (ToList() vs. Single()) I wouldn't be surprised if EF hasn't issued a warning about a Cartesian Product for this query and suggesting `AsSplitQuery()`. Even then, this is pulling a LOT of data that your consumer almost certainly does not need. Flattening or simplifying the data sent back to a view or API consumer will improve query performance and resource usage.

The other thing is when dealing with navigation properties in entities, initialize collections, do not initialize singular references.

```
public virtual StatusType StatusTypes { get; set; } // Don't do this -> = new();
```

Initializing collections is safe, and recommended so that new entities have their child collections ready to go. Initializing something like an Owned reference is Ok, but navigation properties intended to point at many-to-one references should not be initialized. C#10 will complain about uninitialized non-null-able references. This is honestly a case where I just set up the rule supression. An easy way to do so in the entity is to create a protected default constructor and set up the rule suspension around that:

```
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor used by EF.
    /// </summary>
    protected Status() { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
```

Comment: Steve, you've given me a lot to think about.  Thank you.  Some comments back to you: 1) Believe it or not I am using 75% of the data in the graph.  2) I flatten it out in the Domain (business), since how it get flattened is driven by the UI.  3) Status does belong to both Request and Change.  Change has 5 status based on business process and the request is either Open, or Closed once all the changes are closed.  It used to be just Requests with status and I have requirement to add Change status.  It made sense to me to use the same table for both. Bad idea?

Comment: The more I think about it, separating the Request and Change into two graphs will probably go a log way to solving these issues.

For anyone interested, here is a good article on Eager Loading that explains the .ThenInclude.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager